# Cannot use object of type stdClass as array, obtener valor de un array dentro de otro array

Tags: php, laravel, api, rest, woocommerce

Estoy utilizando la API REST de woocommerce en laravel mediante la libreria https://github.com/Codexshaper/laravel-woocommerce, la comparto por si alguien la necesite funciona bastante bien.

El problema actual que tengo es al traer las ultimas ordenes de compra desde la tienda en linea, este devuelve un array que lo recorro con la variable $ordenes, pero a la vez segun la documentacion de la api: https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#list-all-orders, para obteber la informacion de la cantidad comprada se accede a un array dentro del mismo llamado line_items
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
en el esta la propiedad quantity la cual necesito extraer el dato de dicha propiedad para insertarlo luego
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

comparto el codigo de mi controlador

```
  //OBTENER ORDENES DE WOOCOMERCE
           $ordenes= WCOrder::all(['status' => 'processing']);

            foreach($ordenes as $orden){
                $mail =  $orden->billing->email;
               // $customer = Customer::where('email',$mail)->value('id');
                $customer =  Customer::where('email',$mail)->pluck('id')->first();

                $order_id = $orden->id;

                $notes = Note::all($order_id);
                $line_items =  $orden[0]['line_items'][0]->quantity;
               
                // Buscar el cliente por su correo y si no existe crearlo pagina 1
                $neworden = Sale::firstOrCreate(['id_reference_tienda' => $orden->id],
                                ['reference_no' => $orden->id, 'user_id' => '1', 'customer_id' => $customer,
                                'warehouse_id' => '2', 'biller_id' => '1',  'item' => $line_items, 
                                'total_qty'=> $line_items, 'total_discount' => $order->discount_total,
                                'total_tax' => '0',  'total_price' => $orden->total, 'grand_total'=> $orden->total ,
                                'shipping_cost' => $orden->shipping_total, 'sale_status' => '1', 'payment_status'=> '4', 'sale_note' => $notes,
                                'is_active' =>'1']);

            }
```

El error que obtengo siempre manejandolo de distintas formas es: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array
Imagino que es la manera en como estoy tratando el array pero ya lo recorri de diferentes maneras y no logro obtener ese dato en especifico ademas de los demas datos que estan en el array principal.

Comment: Creo que sería bueno que compartieras el array que te devuelve para saber qué estructura tiene y, en dado caso, poderte ayudar.

Comment: Te lo comparto dentro de unos minutos pero lo que devuelve el ejemplo esta aqui https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/?shell#list-all-orders

Comment: Ok, ¿y a qué parte del array deseas acceder? Porque creo que si tus órdenes tienen esa estructura, con hacer `$orders[0]->line_items[0]->quantity;` te traerá la cantidad. Tu problema es que tratas acceder de la siguiente forma: `$orden[0]['line_items'][0]->quantity;` y te da el error, porque no conoce esa key para un array, sino para un objeto. Si te funciona, me dices para marcarla como respuesta.

Comment: *`Cannot use object of type stdClass as array`*  indica que estás tratando un objeto como un array. Por ejemplo, para leer las propiedades de un objeto tendrías que usar la notación: `$elObjeto->laPropiedad`  pero puede que estés usando esta notación que es la de los arrays: `$elObjeto['laPropiedad']` y de ahí el error. Comparte un `var_dump` de tu objeto y podremos ayudarte mejor.

Answer (score 1):

El problema era el siguiente:
Revizando más a detalle el array, dicha propiedad line_items debia ser recorrida por un foreach

```
foreach($orden->line_items as $item)
{
 $item->quantity
}
```

Eso solucionaba el problema, debo de dejar de consejo, siempre revisen el array que devuelva asi como los compañeros que comentaron mencionaron, gracias a ellos por mencionarme el hacer el vardump me di cuenta de ello